# how to set a default value in an array?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

i have an array which contains all the scanned links from a regex format. but in the regex, for www.apple.com, it only has links such as /macbookair/ and /osx/, not http://www.apple.com/macbookair/. is there a way for me to set default values like 'http://www.apple.com/' before the values? that way they are working links. my regex is

```
 /<a(?:[^>]*)href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?:[^>]*)>(?:[^<]*)<\/a>/is
```

is it worth me correcting the above regex? or is there a way to set the default value for an array? i would rather people not mention to use 'html dom' or something like that because i would rather just use one of the ways i suggested.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Not really related, but still: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: Loop over the array, and prepend desired string - it's a line of code.

Comment: @PeeHaa: I disagree. The question here is about the URL, not the HTML.

Comment: implode("http://www.apple.com/", $extracted_array);

Comment: Hmmm what is that regex doing in there than :P @Truth (you may just be right though). "is it worth me correcting the above regex?" The question is just not clear in my defense :)

Comment: would an implode statement do my first task? o.O

Comment: what is your first task?  From your question, i understand that you have an array containing some strings, these values has to be prepended with a string.  implode would do that.

Comment: Or As @moonwave99 suggestion, loop over the array and prepend it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$default_value = 'http://www.apple.com'; // without slash

foreach( $results as &$link )
{
    if( $link[0] == '/' )
    {
        $link = $default_value. $link;
    }
}
```